# Visual Studio 2012 Unable to Create dot42 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dot42

After running through the installation of `dot42`, and specifying both *Visual Studio 2010* integration as well as *Visual Studio 2012* integration, I'm unable to find a 'dot42' project in 2012. In 2010 the new dot42 subcategory opens under `C#` and I'm able to see the project types to create.

I noticed that dot42 installs its dlls in the `Extensions` folder, and looking at the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions` folder, the dot42 files are there, just as they are under `Visual Studio 10.0`.

Why can't I create a dot42 project in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: What edition of VS are you using? You need Pro or higher (Express does not allow extensions).

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention - both 2010 and 2012 are Premium edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated dot42 from version `1.0.0.69` to `1.0.0.70` and the problem has been resolved. I can now create Visual Studio 2012 dot42 projects.

Comment: I liked it - although I still had some troubles opening in __Visual Studio 2012__, I was able to get it to work very well in __Visual Studio 2010__.

Comment: OK, thanks for replying. Have you created any non-trivial apps with it? Would you recommend it for developing a real-world non-trivial app?